# Linq query with toDictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I have the following linq query

```
  var temp = (from p in db.BEM_EVT_FULL
                      where (p.date_reception > dt)
                      group p by p.mc_object into g
                      orderby g.Count() descending
                      select new StringIntType
                      {
                          str = g.Key,
                          nbr = g.Count()
                      }).Take(50).ToList();
```

Instead of casting result to StringIntType i need to use Dictionary with int and string types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var temp = (from p in db.BEM_EVT_FULL
            where (p.date_reception > dt)
            group p by p.mc_object into g
            orderby g.Count() descending
            select new
            {
                Key = g.Key,
                Value = g.Count()
            }).Take(50)
              .ToDictionary(x=>x.Key, y=>y.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like there may be an answer for this question here: [Convert Linq Query Result to Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953919/convert-linq-query-result-to-dictionary)

basically, instead of ToList use ToDictionary

```
.ToDictionary( t => t.Key, t => t.Value);
```