# Convert DataRow to Dictionary using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I need to convert DataRow into Dictionary using LINQ.

The code below will get the DataRow, the next step is I need convert it to dictionary(ColumnName, RowVale)

```
var WorkWeekData = from data in mWorkWeekData.AsEnumerable ()
            where data.Field<string> ("Code") == code
            select data;
```

Comment: chech this [SO link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953919/convert-linq-query-result-to-dictionary)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It's definitely possible, yes:

```
var dict = row.Table.Columns
              .Cast<DataColumn>()
              .ToDictionary(c => c.ColumnName, c => row[c]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You 'can' use this approach but when I tried it, hoping to improve performance, I found it was MUCH slower than using the longer solution.

This way:

```cs
foreach (DataRow row in dtIn.Rows)
{
    dictionary.Clear();
    foreach (DataColumn dataColumn in dtIn.Columns)
    {
        dictionary.Add(dataColumn.ColumnName, row[dataColumn.ColumnName].ToString());
    }
}
```

Is much faster than:

```cs
foreach (DataRow row in dtIn.Rows)
{
    dictionary = row.Table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
        .ToDictionary(c => c.ColumnName, c => row[c].ToString());
}
```

Comment: Just a note that you need to account for nullable columns as well.  .ToString() will throw an error if your value is DBNull.