# Datatable todictionary several columns

Tags: c#, dictionary, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to convert a datatable to a dictionary using the method described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277(v=vs.110).aspx), but I get an error

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary>' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary``.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953919/convert-linq-query-result-to-dictionary) helped, but only one value is pulled into the dictionary, not several which is what I need.

Thanks for any help.

```
public class MCEAV
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int BOOK_ID { get; set; }
    public double DATA { get; set; }
}

Dictionary<int, MCEAV> dctGREEKS = new Dictionary<int, MCEAV>();
dctGREEKS = DATActx.MONTECARLO_EAVs.Select(Z => new { Z.ID, Z.BOOK_ID, Z.DATA}).ToDictionary(Z => Z.ID);
```

Comment: If you have 1 value in `MONTECARLO_EAVs` you'll get one values in the dictionary. That is simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the name of the class when using `new` else it is an anonymous type:

```
dctGREEKS = DATActx.MONTECARLO_EAVs.Select(Z => 
                               new MCEAV()
                               { 
                                  ID = Z.ID, 
                                  BOOK_ID = Z.BOOK_ID, 
                                  DATA = Z.DATA
                               }).ToDictionary(Z => Z.ID);
```

So `new { Z.ID, Z.BOOK_ID, Z.DATA}` is an instance of an anonymous type created by the compiler while `new MCEAV()` is an instance of type `MCEAV` which is what you want for your dictionary.

Comment: Thankyou! this was driving me crazy, I had run ways to get the code to work.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your code, I guess you want something like this.

```
var result = dt.AsEnumerable()
        .ToDictionary(x=>x.Field<int>("ID"), 
                      x=> new MCEAV() 
                      {
                          ID = x.Field<int>("ID"),
                          BOOK_ID = x.Field<int>("BOOK_ID"), 
                          DATA = x.Field<double>("DATA") 

                      });
```

Check this [`Example`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tv6tSz)