# Reading from XML to Dictionary using XmlSerializer?

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, xmlserializer

This array:

```
public List<Publisher> Publishers
{
    get { return _Publishers; }
    set { _Publishers = value; }
}
private List<Publisher> _Publishers;
```

Is used by the `XmlSerializer` to store the data in the XML file.

But in terms of application use, I really need a `Dictionary<string, Publisher>` so that I can quickly find the right `Publisher` object based on the name.

Now, I realise that I can't do this directly using the `XMLSerializer` and that
is why I am using the `List`. Is there any neat way to achieve what I desire once the data is read in from the XML file?

I realise I can iterate the list and build a dictionary. But is there an alternative?

Comment: Create a dictionary from your array and serialize it to store your data....

Comment: But I am using the XML file as my core database here, which reads to / from an array. The dictionary object is a temporary object to manage this list when my application runs.

Comment: this is what you need https://github.com/Atlas-Project/AtlasXmlSerializer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the approach would be to back it with a dictionary, and present the `List` for the serialization. Like this:

```
public List<Publisher> Publishers
{
    get { return _PublishersDictionary.Select(x => x.Value).ToList(); }
    set { _publishersDictionary = value.ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x); }
}
private Dictionary<string, Publisher> _publishersDictionary;

[XmlIgnore]
public Dictionary<string, Publisher> PublisherDictionary
{
    get { return _publishersDictionary; }
}
```

Comment: I end up with an empty XML when I use this approach.

Comment: What does your constructor look like out of interest?

Comment: For the publisher class? Doesn't have one.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Are you setting the property or adding to it? If you are adding to it then there needs to be some mechanism of updating the underlying `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 1):

Would this help.

```
    public List<Publisher> Publishers
    {
        get { return _Publishers; }
        set { _Publishers = value; }
    }
    private List<Publisher> _Publishers;

    private Dictionary<string, Publisher> _PublishersDictionary;
    public Dictionary<string, Publisher> PublisherDictionary
    {
        get
        {
            if(this._PublishersDictionary == null)
            {
                this._PublishersDictionary = this.Publishers.ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p);
            }

            return this._PublishersDictionary;
        }
    }
```

Code Found from [Converting linq query to dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953919/convert-linq-query-result-to-dictionary) I just skipped the linq query result part.

Also if you are serializing this back to the xml the seriliser should ignore this property as it does not have a setter but you could also add the `[xmlIgnore]` attribute above this property.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this.