# Create dictionary outside and initialize it using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have dictionary **indices** and want to add several keys to it from another dictionary using LINQ.

```
var indices = new Dictionary<string, int>();
var source = new Dictionary<string, int> { { "1", 1 }, { "2", 2 } };
source.Select(name => indices[name.Key] = 0); // doesn't work
var res = indices.Count; // returns 0
```

Then I replace Select with Min and everything works as expected, LINQ creates new keys in my dictionary.

```
source.Min(name => indices[name.Key] = 0); // works!!!
var res = indices.Count; // returns 2
```

**Question**

All I want to do is to **initialize dictionary without foreach**. Why dictionary keys disappear when LINQ is executed? What iterator or aggregator I could use instead of Min to create keys for a dictionary declared outside of LINQ query?

**Update #1**

Decided to go with System.Interactive extension.

**Update #2**

I appreciate and upvote all answers, but need to clarify that, purpose of the question is not to copy a dictionary, but to execute some code in a LINQ query. To add more sense to it, I actually have hierarchical structure of classes with dictionaries and at some point they need to be synchronized, so I want to create flat, non-hierarchical dictionary, used for tracking, that includes all hierarchical keys.

```
class Account
{
   Dictionary<string, User> Users;
}

class User
{
   Dictionary<string, Activity> Activities;
}

class Activity
{
   string Name;
   DateTime Time;
}
```

Now I want to sync all actions by time, so I need a tracker that will help me to align all actions by time, and I don't want to create 3 loops for Account, User, and Activity. Because that would be considered a hierarchical hell of loops, the same as async or callback hell. With LINQ I don't have to create loop inside loop, inside loop, etc.

```
Accounts.ForEach(
  account => account.Value.Users.ForEach(
    user => user.Value.Activities.ForEach(
      activity => indices[account.Key + user.Key + activity.Key] = 0));
```

Also, having loops where it can be replaced with LINQ can be considered as a code smell, not my opinion, but I totally agree, because having too many loops you will probably end up in duplicated code.

https://jasonneylon.wordpress.com/2010/02/23/refactoring-to-linq-part-1-death-to-the-foreach/

You can say that LINQ is used for querying, not for setting a variable, I would say I'm querying ... the KEYS.

Comment: what is wrong with `foreach`?

Comment: `Min` (as well as `ToList`, `Count` etc.) *materializes* the result (you get a value, collection, `int`) when `Select` alone *does nothing* (deferred execution). I doubt if you should avoid plain and easy to read `foreach` but expoit the *side effect* of `Min`

Comment: Go NuGet Microsoft's "System.Interactive" extensions and then you can do `source.ForEach(name => indices[name.Key] = 0);`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Linq Query Result to Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953919/convert-linq-query-result-to-dictionary)

Comment: `source.Keys.ToList().ForEach(key => indices[key] = 0);` . Or `source.Keys.ForEach(key => indices[key] = 0);` if you add https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/ to your project.

Comment: Interessing question!. Give you 1 upvote

Comment: `All I want to do is to initialize dictionary without foreach` Are you aware that LINQ is effectively using foreach internally? You can't access all members of a collection without iterating over the collection. That's literally the intention of iterating over the collection.

Comment: Linq is for querying data structures, not for settings values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq is not intended to be used to mutate the elements of a sequence. Rather, it is intended to be used to traverse, filter and project elements of a sequence. In this respect, it is intended to be used more in a "functional programming" style.

As you have discovered, Linq *can* be used in other than a functional programming style - but by using it in that way you are really misusing it.

Technically, the reason that `source.Min()` has the effect you were looking for is that it has to visit each of the elements of your sequence in order to determine the minimum element.

Because your *selector* for `Min()` has a side-effect (i.e. `indices[name.Key] = 0`) then a side-effect of finding the minimum value is to add each element's key to `indices`, but with a value of zero rather than the original value.

(I suspect you might have meant to put `indices[name.Key] = name.Value`...)

The reason that your use of `Select()` has no effect is that it has not been used to traverse the sequence - it uses ["deferred execution"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/charlie/2007/12/10/linq-and-deferred-execution/).

You can force it to traverse the sequence by counting the elements, like so:

```
source.Select(name => indices[name.Key] = 0).Count();
```

However, that is also counter-intuitive and is a misuse of Linq.

The correct solution is to use `foreach`. This expresses your intent clearly and unambiguously.

An alternative approach is to write an `AddRange()` extension method for `Dictionary` like so:

```
public static class DictionaryExt
{
    public static Dictionary<TKey, TValue> AddRange<TKey, TValue>(
        this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> self, 
        IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> items)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            self[item.Key] = item.Value;
        }

        return self;
    }
}
```

Then you can just call `indices.AddRange(source);` to achieve your aim.

Interestingly, the `ImmutableDictionary` type does already have an `AddRange()` method that you could use like so:

```
var indices = ImmutableDictionary.Create<string, int>();
var source  = new Dictionary<string, int> { { "1", 1 }, { "2", 2 } };

indices = indices.AddRange(source);

Console.WriteLine(indices.Count);
```

But I wouldn't recommend you change over to using `ImmutableDictionary` just so you can use its `AddRange()`.

Also note that `ImmutableDictionary` is, well, *immutable* - so you can't just do `indices.AddRange(source);`; you have to assign the result back as in `indices = indices.AddRange(source);` (like when you modify a string using `ToUpper()`).

Comment: I like the explanation, and consider it an answer, but prefer System.Interactive extension as was suggested in comments

Comment: @Anonymous I still think that using `foreach` is the better way to go - [here's a blog post about why a `ForEach` extension method isn't a good idea](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericwhite/2009/04/08/why-i-dont-use-the-foreach-extension-method/). But it's up to you. A significant number of people do use such an extension! :)

Answer (score 2):

You wrote:

> All I want to do is to initialize dictionary without foreach

Do you want to replace the values in your `indices` dictionary with the values in `source`? Use [Enumerable.ToDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
indices = (KeyValuePair<string, int>)source  // regard the items in the dictionary as KeyValuePairs
    .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key,          // the key is the key from original dictionary
                  pair => pair.Value);       // the value is the value from the original
```

Or do you want to add the values from source to the already existing values in `indices`? If you don't want a foreach you'll have to take the current values from both dictionaries and [Concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894(v=vs.110).aspx) them to the values from source. Then use the ToDictionary to create a new Dictionary.

```
indices = (KeyValuePair<string, int>) indices
   .Concat(KeyValuePair<string, int>) source)
   .ToDictionary(... etc)
```

However this would be a waste of processing power.

Consider creating extension functions for Dictionary. [See Extension Methods Demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

```
public static Dictionary<TKey, TValue> Copy>Tkey, TValue>(
    this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> source)
{
     return source.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
}

public static void AddRange<TKey, TValue>(
    this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> destination,
    Dictionary<TKey, TValue> source)
{
     foreach (var keyValuePair in source)
     {
         destination.Add(keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value);
         // TODO: decide what to do if Key already in Destination
     }
}
```

Usage:

```
// initialize:
var indices = source.Copy();
// add values:
indices.AddRange(otherDictionary);
```